# Как увеличить таймаут получения ответа по запросу в Jenkins? Через 60 секунд выходит ошибка JenkinsRest.JenkinsClientRequestGateWayTimeOutException

Tags: rest, jenkins, timeout

При запуске Job выходит ошибка:
JenkinsRest.JenkinsClientRequestGateWayTimeOutException: The request has failed with status code GatewayTimeout and description Gateway Timeout. Response content : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Ошибка возникает, если за 60 секунд мы не получаем ответ по запросу. Где со стороны jenkins устанавливается таймаут по получению ответа на запросы? Как его можно увеличить?

Answer (score 0):

надо под рутом зайти в каталог: `/lib/systemd/system/`
потом: `nano jenkins.service`
Найти там [Service]
и прописать

```
TimeoutStartSec=600
```

Ну и затем(в командной строке): `sudo apt-get install -f`